# How to get Frequent Itemset values when using FPGrowth with rapidminer?

Tags: groovy, rapidminer

In **rapidminer**,the application of **FPgrowth algorithm** didn't gives instances of attributes but it gives the name of the attribute and its support. My question is how to get the value of the attribute via `Groovy`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the implementation of fpgrowth in rapidminer accepts only binomial values which means **binary fpgrowth implementation. IF the attribute has value, fpgrowth read it as 1 otherwise it is considered as 0.
The solution is to create new operator implementing non linear fpgrowth.
and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The FPGrowth algorithm is an algorithm that treat binary values. So RapidMiner's FPGrowth treat any attribute as binary.